# Not pull back data on model change

Tags: java, android, model-view-controller, architecture

I have simple architecture:

```
class Model extends java.util.Observable {
...
public void setData(Data newData) {...}
}
```

And in `Activity.onResume` I subscribe on Model updates (`Activity.onPause` I unsubscribe),
and in implementation of `java.uitl.Observer.update`,
I update GUI (several `EditText`). Use case: data is update from network.

But what to do if update `Model` from GUI (I mean user input something into `EditText` and I want save data into `Model`)?

Unsubscribe before update and subscribe after,
add into `Model` method like update without calling observers?

What common way to deals with situation like this?

Answer (score 0):

I would not put the update code on `Model`. Have another class dedicated to that:

```
class UpdateHandler extends java.util.Observable {
    // GUI update code
}
```

This solves your "where did this update come from?' problem, as well as making `Model` reusable. For instance in the future if you need to port to some other GUI platform...

Comment: But does this make code more fragile? Developers of code should know hey, I have update form network, then I should update data via `UpdateHandler`, hey I have update from GUI I should update data via `Model`. In other words that break encapsulation principle?

Comment: Well, if you look at it from a separation of concerns standpoint, `Model` is supposed to just hold the data, and maybe encapsulate whatever logic that is directly related to the data itself, however, it does not need to be concerned with how the data is presented, or what happens when the data changes, because that may vary from application to application, or even between different parts of the same application.